# How to find extra points of a graph in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have a list:

```
list = {{-4, -7, -3}, {-2, -5, -1}, {1, -2, -3}, {2, -1, 3}, {5, 2, 
1}, {7, 4, 3}};
```

I want to make all functions, e.g $f(x) = \dfrac{(x+4)(x+7)}{x-3}$ and find all extra points for the graph in that list.
I tried

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
myfunction[{a_, b_, c_}] := {(x - a) (x - b)/(x - c), 
   Reduce[D[(x - a) (x - b)/(x - c), x] == 0, x, Reals]};
list = {{-4, -7, -3}, {-2, -5, -1}, {1, -2, -3}, {2, -1, 3}, {5, 2, 
    1}, {7, 4, 3}};
Map[myfunction, list]
```

> {{((4 + x) (7 + x))/(3 + x), x == -5 || x == -1}, {((2 + x) (5 + x))/(
> 1 + x), x == -3 || x == 1}, {((-1 + x) (2 + x))/(3 + x),
> x == -5 || x == -1}, {((-2 + x) (1 + x))/(-3 + x),
> x == 1 || x == 5}, {((-5 + x) (-2 + x))/(-1 + x),
> x == -1 || x == 3}, {((-7 + x) (-4 + x))/(-3 + x),
> x == 1 || x == 5}}

With the function (4 + x) (7 + x))/(3 + x), I want to show the extra points $(-5,1)$ and $(-1,9)$ in `myfunction[{a_, b_, c_}]` like this?

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but are you looking for: `myfunction[{a_, b_, c_}] := {(x - a) (x - b)/(x - c), {x, (x - a) (x - b)/(x - c)} /. Solve[D[(x - a) (x - b)/(x - c), x] == 0, x, Reals]}` ?

Comment: @Domen You understand my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify, we define 3 separate functions. The first is the actual function with an arbitrary argument:

```
f[{a_, b_, c_}, x_] = (x - a) (x - b)/(x - c);
```

The second is a function that returns the roots of the derivative and the function values at the roots:

```
roots[arg : {a_, b_, c_}] := Module[{z},
  {z, f[arg, z]} /. {ToRules[Reduce[D[f[arg, z], z] == 0, z, Reals]]}
```

The third function simply assemble the output:

```
myfun[arg : {a_, b_, c_}] := {f[arg, x], roots[arg]};
```

With this, we may write:

```
list = {{-4, -7, -3}, {-2, -5, -1}, {1, -2, -3}, {2, -1, 3}, {5, 2, 
    1}, {7, 4, 3}};
myfun /@ list
```

[image]